# Шаринг данных между своими приложениями на разных платформах (macOS, iOS)

Tags: ios, macos, хранение-данных

Каким наиболее простым способом можно расшарить данные между своими приложениями iOS и macOS без использования сервера (аналог app groups).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону `iCloud Ubiquity Container`. [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17117259/608343) для ознокомления.